# How to wait for a large number packet erminator pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am debugging packets sent from a device with pyserial. The packets have a specific terminator pattern to differentiate between packets of data. The pattern is a large number (0x3423fe67). I am able to receive bytes and concatenate them as they come in with the code below.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
                    ports="/dev/ttyUSB0",
                    baudrate=115200,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

y = b''
while True:
    bytes = ser.inWaiting()
    if bytes > 0:
        x = ser.read(bytes)
        y += binascii.hexify(x)
        print(y)
```

I can see the pattern I'm looking for but how do I grab the packet and terminator once I see the terminator. I tried indexing the bytes object but that returns strange values. Everything received before the terminator is part of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that accumulates packets in a list.  The code can be used as a guide.

The serialData is data that would be received over the serial port as an example (i.e. ser.read() which would replace the for piece in x: loop).  Note that an arbitrary number of bytes can be received, and the test variable n is only used to test the algorithm at arbitrary incoming received character lengths.

The term variable needed hexlify to match the hexlify on the incoming data.

```
    import binascii
    import re

    term = binascii.hexlify(b'\x34\x23\xfe\x67')
    serialData = b'packet0\x34\x23\xfe\x67packet1\x34\x23\xfe\x67'
    n = 5
    x = [serialData[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(serialData), n)]

    y = b''
    packets = []
    for piece in x:
        y += binascii.hexlify(piece)
        for i in re.finditer(term, y):
            packets.append(y[:i.start()])
            y = y[i.end():]

    print('packets = ', packets)
```